# Permission option for unblock the selected users not listed

Tags: users

I have created a user & assingned it role 'superuser'.I want to give only two permissions to superuser, block the selected user account & unblock the selected user account.I have given 'block selected user' permission from admin->people->permission but the option for 'unblock the selected user account' permission is not listed in admin->people->permission.How can i give this permission to superuser?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view and give access to superuser role.

Below links will help you.

http://blog.safwan.in/post/69263954822/add-unblock-user-action-to-views-bulk-operation-vbo

http://dropbucket.org/node/486

Comment: I tried with module in the link,but its not showing an option'unblock the user' for superuser role.

Comment: Create a page view of users,under Page settings give access only to superuser role.Under fields add users bulk operations and enable block and unblock users. HTH..

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the same links and created the module at some extent it is working fine that is there is an option "Unblock the user" is appearing in views bulk operation and permissions. But the problem, is it is not Unblocking the user in actual.